# Pentaho how to avoid useless Karaf 100 seconds timeout

Tags: timeout, pentaho

We do a lot of testing on Pentaho jobs, but each time we have to wait for 1 minute 40 seconds before anything happens. The cause must be Karaf because of this output message of Kitchen:

```
11:55:58,432 ERROR [KarafLifecycleListener] The Kettle Karaf Lifecycle Listener
failed to execute properly after waiting for 100 seconds.
Releasing lifecycle hold, but some services may be unavailable.
```

Some people suggested to add a line to kettle.properties in your home dir, or in folder .pentaho or .kettle like below, but this had no effect:

```
KITCHEN_KARAF_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=20
```

The other approach would be to give Karaf something to listen to so that it will stop waiting any further, but I could not find info on this.

How do we avoid that 100 seconds of waiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need Karaf, you can remove these files and folder:

```
\classes\kettle-lifecycle-listeners.xml
\classes\kettle-registry-extensions.xml
\lib\org.apache.karaf.*.jar
\system\karaf
```

Comment: What if I just want to disable the logging and not everything in karaf? Is there something I can comment out?