# Pentaho 9.1 CE JAVA8. Disable KARAF

Tags: pentaho, apache-karaf

Tell me how to disable KARAF in Pentaho 9.1 CE+JAVA8?

I deleted the files as instructed ([Pentaho how to avoid useless Karaf 100 seconds timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74717008/pentaho-how-to-avoid-useless-karaf-100-seconds-timeout))
Delete files:
`\classes\kettle-lifecycle-listeners.xml \classes\kettle-registry-extensions.xml \lib\org.apache.karaf.*.jar \system\karaf`
,
but the "connect" button disappeared. During the experiment, I learned that file
`\classes\kettle-registry-extensions.xml`
is responsible for it. Is it possible to disable KARAF without removing the connect button?